# Using supervisord and rvm to run rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, supervisord, sysv

I have a RubyOnRails 3 project and I'm using rvm. I want to switch from a sysvinit script to supervisord. The sysvinit script can only start the software in case of an error it it gets killed and restarted by $something. Mostly me.

In the project folder there is a `.ruby-version` and a `.ruby-gemset` file so that the correct ruby version and gemset gets loaded automatically. Then the app is startet with a shell script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

RAILS_ENV="production" rails server -d
```

My init script looks like this and works besides restarting and stopping:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myapp
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts myapp
# Description:       starts the myapp software
### END INIT INFO

USER=myuser
PATH=$PATH
DAEMON=go.sh
DAEMON_OPTS=""
NAME=myapp
DESC="myapp for $USER"
PID=/home/$USER/myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

case "$1" in
  start)
        CD_TO_APP_DIR="cd /home/$USER/myapp"
        START_DAEMON_PROCESS="$DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS"

        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        if [ $(whoami) = root ]; then
          su - $USER -c "$CD_TO_APP_DIR > /dev/null 2>&1 && ./$START_DAEMON_PROCESS &"
        else
          $CD_TO_APP_DIR > /dev/null 2>&1 && ./$START_DAEMON_PROCESS &
        fi
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        kill -QUIT `cat $PID`
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  restart)
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        kill -USR2 `cat $PID`
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  reload)
        echo -n "Reloading $DESC configuration: "
        kill -HUP `cat $PID`
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart|reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

My supervisor config looks like this:

```
[program:myapp]
directory=/home/myuser/myapp/
command=/home/myuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.5@myapp/rails server -d
environment=RAILS_ENV="production"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Problem is that there is no rails binary in the wrapper. so that the command fails. What is the correct way to do this? I'm out of ideas and would start putting some really ugly bash script together that does the job in a very wrong and bad way but does it. Btw I found rails in the gems folder.

```
$ ls /home/myuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.5@myapp/
bundle  bundler  erb  executable-hooks-uninstaller  gem  irb  rake  rdoc  ri  ruby  testrb
$ which rails
/home/ffwi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ffwi-extern/bin/rails
```

Comment: I believe you need a command like:
`command=/home/myuser/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.5@myapp/bundle exec rails server -d`

Comment: Supervisor says [not to daemonize](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#nondaemonizing-of-subprocesses) your subprocesses so don't use the `-d` option on `rails server`

Answer (score 0):

Try to source rvm in your script (this [link](https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting) describes usecases like yours).

You have to load RVM into the shell of your script manually:

```
    source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

It is only enabled for interactive login shells automatically.

From this point on, you can `cd` into directories and rvm should do its business.